# Change Border in Excel left, right, bottom and top

Tags: c#, excel, border

Firstly, I changed color borders of my sheet to white, because I want to have a white sheet.

Then I made some headers and want to make a border around it. The problem is that it made borders between the values in header, but top, down are not visible.

**My code:**

```
xlWorkSheet5.Columns.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White); // Color Sheet5 to white, BusLoad
xlWorkSheet5.Columns.NumberFormat = "@";

Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet5.get_Range("A7","J7");
rng.RowHeight = 25.5;

rng.BorderAround2(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlHairline, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic);
rng.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
rng.Borders.Weight = 1d;

rng.Font.Bold = true;
rng.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
rng.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
```

Comment: use `BorderAround` in stead of `BorderAround2`?

Comment: @K_B: i tried it but the result is the same

Comment: WIth your very first line of code you dont change the color of the cells to white, but that of the borders...

Comment: ach yes, didn't notice it :p, but how can i delete borders color accept Header?

Comment: If no answer will be given: you could try to not call a method (like `BorderAround`) but the underlying range property in stead (`Borders`)

Comment: By default a spreadsheet will not have borders , you will just see those grey lines intended as assistance by Microsoft. You can get rid of those by either: filling all cells `Interior` with a color (for example White) OR making all `Borders` the same color as the cells `Interior` OR by disabling the Gridlines option (menu View and in code `Application.DisplayGridlines = False` | `True`

Comment: yes i'm thinking about `rng.Borders.top = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous` or something like that, could anyone give me an advice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK I found a solution to do it, here is my code:

```
xlWorkSheet5.Cells[7,1].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Weight = 1d;
xlWorkSheet5.Cells[7, 1].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 1d;
xlWorkSheet5.Cells[7,1].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight = 1d;
xlWorkSheet5.Cells[7,1].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = 1d;
```

Comment: This can also be done using a single line of code `xlWorkSheet5.Cells[7,1].Borders.Weight = 1d;`

Comment: @Wayne But that single line of code won't capture different border weight on sides, rather it'll apply same value to all sides.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the Borders[index] property then use something along the lines of:

```
rng.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
rng.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].ColorIndex = <COLOR THAT YOU WANT>

rng.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop]...
rng.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom]...
rng.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight]...
```

Answer (score 1):

Border.Weight property

XlBorderWeight can be one of these XlBorderWeight constants: xlHairline xlThin xlMedium xlThick.

Example for create continuous line on Cells from Bx to Mx, where x is number of line

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Range line = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.Rows[1]; 
line.Insert();

excelWorksheet.Range[$"B{1}:M{1}"].Cells.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
excelWorksheet.Range[$"B{1}:M{1}"].Cells.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
```